# Getting the links containing an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var thumbs = $("#thumbs img");
var links = $("#thumbs a");
```

This gives me two variables which contain all the images and links within the 'thumbs' div ID.

What I need is an array that would contain the links wrapped around the image tags like this:

```
<a href="www.google.com"><img src="image1.gif"></a>
```

This is what the code already looks like within the 'thumbs' div. Should I be using the `.children()` method?  If so could you please show me an example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exact need isn't clear but it seems you want

```
$("#thumbs a > img"); // images wrapped directly in links
```

or

```
$("#thumbs a:has(img)"); // the links around the images
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#thumbs a img').map(function() {
   return $(this).parents('a').attr('href');
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the closest function to go "backwards" from whatever is selected.

First you find all img tags that are immediate siblings of anchors (no intermediate tags), then you go back to the anchors.

```
$("#thumbs a > img").closest('a');
```